# Rearranging open programs in Fedora task bar

Tags: fedora, gnome

Is it possible to rearrange the order applications appear in the bottom task bar for Fedora (27)

---

See also this question on a different ubuntu OS.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/280692/how-do-i-reorder-buttons-in-the-window-list-taskbar-via-drag-and-drop

I can't find a similar option as proposed in the solutions for Fedora.

---

The window list is provided by an extension found in Tweak
(window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com),

the settings offer almost no options and certainly not this one, so I think the answer is no (or is there some other extension I could use?).

Comment: Fedora Workstation 27 does not show a bottom task bar in the default session. Please be a bit more specific. E.g. did you choose a "GNOME Classic" session when logging in?

Comment: @sourcejedi. I use it at work and did not do any set up myself. So I don't know. I did not make such a choice. Is there any place where I can find the answers to this questions? (Any useful log of this type of information that I can get to). 

I tried the following already (don't know whether this is the information you want):
From `env`:

`XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME`

`GDMSESSION=gnome`

and

`$DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome`

Comment: From that, I'd guess it's _not_ "GNOME Classic", just "GNOME", and you have an extension installed. You could confirm that at the login screen. When you login in to GDM, there's a cog underneath the password box. Clicking on it gives you a choice of session types. If "GNOME Classic" is selected (has a dot next to it), you're using GNOME Classic. Inside gnome, if you have the "Tweaks" app available, you can look at the Extensions tab to see what is enabled, it's probably just the standard one called "Windows list". I don't know if there is any way to manually re-order the list of windows in it.

Comment: If you don't have Tweaks, you might be able to see if the standard extension is enabled by visiting https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/602/window-list/ in your browser (seriously), and looking for the on/off toggle

Comment: Looks like you can also check the list of extensions on the command line using `dconf read /org/gnome/shell/enabled-extensions`. The one I see in Tweaks is called 'window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com'